# Get some informations of my screens

Tags: batch-file, cmd, screen, information-extraction

I wanted to ask if there was any way to get the information of my computers screens so I could put those informations into a database as well. But so far I haven't managed to find any solution on the internet except one guy who shares his visual basic script which I actually don't really want to use unless I understand it completely.

I mean no one with his right mind would just run an unknown script, which could execute anything on his computer and he would probably not know what has happened. I think there must be some way to get the information of the screens.

This would be the last bit to finish my work on a batch script which would collect a lot of information which I will only have to put inside a database afterwards or perhaps I will work on a second script to do that for me. But the important part is: "How can I get the Information of my screens via a batch script.?"

I mean there must be some way and I am sure there must be something like wmic display get serialnumber or similar to retrieve the information.

The only information I need is the mark, the serialnumber and the modell of the screen.

Comment: and what information you want to get?

Comment: @npocmaka, I think they want the make, model and serial numbers of their display monitor(s)

Comment: @npocmaka I want to get informations like Manufacturer, Serialnumber, Model but if you have skipped my last line you will probably have missed this bit of informations:
"The only information I need is the mark, the serialnumber and the modell of the screen."

Answer (score 2):

you have two options (though if there are no additional drivers installed the information will be generic)

1) Wmic:

```
wmic path Win32_DesktopMonitor  get /format:value
```

and also (check the [Compo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) comment):

```
WMIC /NameSpace:\\Root\WMI Path WmiMonitorID Get /format:value
```

2) DxDiag:

```
start "" /w dxdiag /t "%cd%\~.txt"
```

DxDiag cant print information into the console but will create a text file with the system information (including the monitor one) which you can filter later with `FIND` or `FINDSTR` information.If you need further help please check the output of the two commands and tell what you need to be saved.

Comment: Win32_DesktopMonitor doesn't have the serial number, but `WmiMonitorID` may have `SerialNumberID` as an unsigned 16bit integer.

Comment: @Compo - thanks.Good to know.I'll update the answer.

Comment: Here's the command, _(Vista+)_, `WMIC /NameSpace:\\Root\WMI Path WmiMonitorID Get SerialNumberID`, I hope the conversion is fun!

Comment: @Compo thank you for the help with this. It actually helps a lot. The only problem it, that I don't recieve the Model of the screens. Would be much faster to read out that information as well. The conversion should be no problem. I will just have to get the values, write them into a temporary text file which will be deleted afterwards and I will try to work something out to give me the proper manufacturer name. Thanks a lot compo. P.s.: The dxdiag doesn't really create a filename or am I missing something?